# Fetching data from database according to form values

Tags: java, css, mysql, database

I am trying to fetch cost from database table by name. I get the costs from table but I need to print total. Here is my code.

By this I get the names of service

```
<% String [] s = request.getParameterValues("service");
             out.println(""+Arrays.toString(s)+"");
%>
```

and by this getting cost from table

```
<% 
   ResultSet resultset=null;
   int i=0;
   for(String st : s)
   {
       resultset = statement.executeQuery("select cost from service where name='" + st +"'");

       while(resultset.next()){ 
           i=resultset.getInt("cost");
           out.println(i); 
       }
   }

%>
```

I want cost to be displayed as total.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you are looking for this :

```
<% 
   ResultSet resultset=null;
   int i=0;
   int total = 0;
   for(String st:s)
   {
      resultset = statement.executeQuery("select cost from service where name='" + st +"'");
      while(resultset.next())
      { 
         i=resultset.getInt("cost");
         total=total+i;
         out.println(i); 
       }
   }
   out.println(total); 

 %>
```